# getJSON method returns 'undefined' in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on an Asp.net core 2.1 project and have the below model

**Person**

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Family { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

There is a web API controller in my project that you can see it.

**Web API Controller**

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/People")]
public class PeopleController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly ApplicationContext _db;

    public PeopleController(ApplicationContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPerson()
    {
        return _db.Person;
    }
}
```

Now I want to get data from my web API controller and show in `index.cshtml`

**Index.cshtml**

```
<h2>List Person</h2>

<table class="table table-bordered" id="list">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Family</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  $.getJSON("/api/People", function(res) {
    $.each(res, function(key, val) {
      alert(val.Age);
      var item =
        "<tr><td>" +
        val.ID +
        "</td><td>" +
        val.Name +
        "</td><td>" +
        val.Family +
        "</td><td>" +
        val.Age +
        "</td><td></td></tr>";

      $("#list").append(item);
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Actual Json in Network Tab in browser**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"jack","family":"bfd","age":30},{"id":2,"name":"mr john","family":"sobhany","age":36}]
```

But there is a problem. All data shows in my view but all values are `undefined`.
What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: What does the actual JSON look like (e.g., in the browser's Network tab)?

Comment: Network tab is empty in my browser @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Then you need to ensure you perform the request with the network tab open (I guess you're using Edge or some other browser where the network tab only records things when it's open). If you're geting a response at all, clearly a network request is happening, which will show up in the network tab.

Comment: Now i perform it with chrome browser and `Network` tab and `Response` shows value correctly. But shows `undefined` in my view. @T.J. Crowder

Comment: Again: What is the actual JSON? Please use the "edit" link to copy-and-paste it from the Network tab into the question.

Comment: This is a guess, but in your `GetPerson` method, I would expect you to return a specific item from the person table, and not the whole table. I would expect something like this: `return PeopleDB.People.First(x => x.Id == Id);` - and then you send the Id as a parameter to the method.

Comment: i edited question and add actual json in network tab @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Please note to method type `IEnumerable<Person>` @thesystem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see looking at the JSON, your JSON serializer is converting your C#-oriented names like `Name` (note: first letter capitalized) to JavaScript-oriented ones like `name` (note: first letter in lower case):

```
[{"id":1,"name":"jack","family":"bfd","age":30},{"id":2,"name":"mr john","family":"sobhany","age":36}]
Note ----^^^^^^
```

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language, so naturally `val.Name` is `undefined` because there's no `Name` property on `val`; you want `val.name` instead (and so on for `id`, `family`, `bfd`, `age`...).